# DF Column Values Replace fxn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace multiple names throughout my entire DF to match a certain output. For example how can I make it where the DF will replace all "Ronald Acuna" with "Ronald Acuna Jr." and "Corbin Burns" to "Corbin B"

[image]

lineups.replace(to_replace = ['Corbin Burnes'], value ='Corbin B')

This works, but then when I make another line for Ronald Acuna, Corbin B goes back to his full name. Im sure there is a way to somehow loop it all together, but I can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, it is best practice to include the code you are working with or the data, rather than an image. It will help you get better answers.

Comment: You are right! My apologies, new to this whole space.

Comment: Not a problem! I'm learning too. If you found the answer I posted sufficient, I think you can mark the question as solved or answered.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will need to reassign the new replaced dataframe back to the dataframe

```
lineups = lineups.replace(to_replace = ['Corbin Burnes'], value ='Corbin B')

lineups = lineups.replace(to_replace = ['Ronald Acuna'], value ='Ronald Acuna Jr')
```

And so on.

Comment: wow i completely missed reassigning it! Thanks! This will definitely work for they time being

Comment: I have another question, if corbin burnes wasnt in the data frame would it error out?

Comment: Here is the documentation for the replace function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html it either returns `Object after replacement or None if inplace=True.`

Comment: I just experimented and if there is no value to replace, the replace function just returns the dataframe. So it does not error out.